# Can't find items in control panel

Tags: windows-10, control-panel

On my laptop, I can't find items in the control panel. Whatever I type (and I know it existed on Windows 7), nothing will be found.

Interestingly, when I type it in the start menu, the item will appear, but when I click on it, it just brings me to the empty control panel.

What's wrong with my Windows 10 and how do I fix that?

Examples when I try to find the disk partitioning utility:

[image: Entering "disk" in the start menu]

[image: Finding "disk" in the control panel]

This is a legal Windows Version 10.0.10586, which came with my Lenovo Ideapad. It has not been upgraded from Windows 7.

The disk partitioning tool itself works. When I run `diskmgmt.msc` it opens. But that's harder to achieve than just typing `disk`.

Comment: If you search "Control Panel" what do you see?

Comment: @TimmyJim In the start menu, I see "Systemsteuerung", the German word for control panel. Clicking it, I get the "old" control panel. Searching for "disk" there finds the disk partitioning utility.

Comment: Hmm.  I think what you are looking for is under Administrative tools now.  Search Administrative Tools instead, double click Computer Management, and then select Disk Management.  I also was able to find the same thing by searching Disk partitions in the search bar.

Comment: @TimmyJim: as shown in the screenshot, it finds the correct item in the start menu, but clicking it opens the wrong (second screenshot)

Comment: I see them.  Its odd that we are getting different things.  I know the search feature can be a little annoying at times and sometimes you need to type more than just say "disk" to get what you are looking for, hence why I ask to search Disk Partitions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Search service is running. If it's not, start `services.msc`, and set `Windows Search` service start type to Automatic. Start the service.

Then, open this folder:

```
 C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\
```

Right-click `LocalState` and click Properties. Click Advanced.

In the `Advanced Attributes` dialog, enable the following option:

```
Allow files in this folder to have contents indexed in addition to file properties
```

Wait for some time for search to index that folder and all the XML files in it. If that doesn't still work rebuild the index manually.

([Src](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-settings-search-no-results-found-fix/))

Comment: The service was already running, so it must have been the "allow ... indexed" setting on that folder.